# Transparent UART - read characterstic gets be ASCII as well as equivalent hex

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is my first project on Android App Development.
I was trying to communicate with a custom device which reads some counts.
I was able to tweak the [BluetoothLEGatt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt) and able to read the characterstic which is intended to get me the values in it.

I read the values and populate it to the TextView object. The value which I read has the ASCII values and corresponding hex!!.

**Ex: 000001,2 30 30 30 30 30 31 2A 32** 
I require just the ASCII values and do not need their hex equivalents.

I tried to read the characteristic with the [LightBlue](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.punchthrough.lightblueexplorer&hl=en_IN) app and I got only hex values. No Ascii.

**Ex: 30 30 30 30 31 2A 32**

Please provide me hints on what could make my BLE device transmit both ASCII and hex values?